# is it possible to use google analytics' regex search to find matched search queries that don't have specific words?

Tags: regex, google-analytics

I want to do a search on "matched search queries" in google analytics so i can find all search results people use to come to my site that don't exclude certain words. For instance, lets say I made a list of searches that include the word "flower" using the regex `(flower[^l])|(flower$)`. Now, i want to make a list of all searches that dont include the word flower, so i have a mutually exclusive and exhaustive list. However, i read that google cant really handle negative results, thus expressions like the one in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406230/regular-expression-to-match-string-not-containing-a-word) won't work in google analytics.

To go one step further, lets say i made 3 lists, 1 list each for each of the regexes:

`(flower[^l])|(flower$)`, `(pot[^l])|(pot$)`, and `9 ?x ?9`

Is it possible to create a regex that works in google analytics to make a list of all the searches that didn't match the above regexes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Next to the search box is link labeled "advanced".  Click on that and you get some advanced search fields to use.  Change the "Include" dropdown to "**Exclude**".  Change "Containing to "Match RegExp".  In the box next to that, enter in your regex as if you were looking **for** it. The **Exclude** dropdown will now make the report filter by anything that did *not* match the regex.

Comment: I completely overlooked the "exclude/include" dropdown on the side there. duh. Thanks!